# Remove item and if order has no more items then remove whole order

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Below code never removes order, even if last item was removed - why ? I would like to remove also order if there is no more items?

```
    int orderItemId = 5;
    OrderItem orderItem = DbContext.OrderItem.Find(orderItemId);
    Order order = DbContext.Order.Find(orderItem.OrderId);

    DbContext.OrderItem.Remove(orderItem);

    if (DbContext.OrderItem.Count(x => x.OrderId == order.Id) == 0)
    {
           DbContext.Order.Remove(order);
    }

    DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DbContext.OrderItem.Remove(orderItem); // [1]

if (DbContext.OrderItem.Count(x => x.OrderId == order.Id) == 0) // [2]
{
    DbContext.Order.Remove(order);
}

DbContext.SaveChanges(); // [3]
```

When you remove `orderItem` from `OrderItem` collection on `[1]` line, it is not actually removed in database. Item will be removed only on `SaveChanges()` call on `[3]` line. Until that, `orderItem` is just posted for removal but not removed.

But when you query for count of items on `[2]` line - it is queried from database, which is sill contains `orderItem`.

You need to submit your changes to database before checking for existing items:

```
DbContext.OrderItem.Remove(orderItem);
DbContext.SaveChanges();

if (!DbContext.OrderItem.Any(x => x.OrderId == order.Id))
{
    DbContext.Order.Remove(order);
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: But what if something goes wrong during DbContext.SaveChanges() inside IF statement? There will be order without items in database.

Comment: @MrChudz In any way two consequent updates cannot be atomic without transaction. EF does not any magic. You ask for deletion of items from two tables, EF will execute two separate deletions. In your particular case you HAVE to execute one delete before querying for existing items and do consequent delete. And the only way to do it as atomic operation is transaction.

Comment: @MrChudz By the way, `Any` would be more appropriate (and slightly faster) then `Count` since it will generate `select top 1 ...` query. No need to scan entire table/index if you have at least one item already found and that enough for your check. Updated answer to refer that.

Comment: @MrChudz Read how to use transactions with EF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the item to remove first, then refresh. Try this as a more robust solution and tell me what result you get:

```
var id = "2";
var orderItem = db.OrderItems.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);

if(orderItem != null)
{
    // The items exists. So we remove it and calling 
    // the db.SaveChanges this will be removed from the database.
    db.OrderItems.Remove(orderItem);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Refresh or update any visible data with the new data source.
    refreshGrid();
}
else {
    // Replace orderItem.Id with identifying order item property.
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format("Attempted to remove order {0}, but it could not be found.", orderItem.Id)
    );
}
```

Comment: What is refreshGrid ?

Comment: A method to refresh whatever data sources you're displaying with new data. Just there as an example, I'll add a few more code comments.